# PHP die() clean all page

Tags: php

A php die function question.
when I use die(), it clean all page elements.
Is any way to echo error message and not clean all page, It looks like jump to another page when I use die() to stop code and call out the message.

Here are my code

```
    <?PHP
$message="";
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];

    //Field check
    if($name && $password){$message=$name . $password;}
    else{die($message="please enter name and password");}

    //Check name    
    if($name=="alex" && $password==123){$message="Welcome ". $name;}    
    else{$message="wrong user or password";}
    }
?>

<html>
<p>SIGN UP</p>
    <form action="testing.php" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name" />
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password"/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign up"/>
    </form>
    <div><?PHP echo $message?></div>
</html>
```

Comment: dont use die then :) what do you want to happen again, if you could be more clearer.

Comment: don't use die(), just set $message.

Comment: `die` is pretty radical, you almost certainly don't want to use it.

Comment: because if i dont use die()
php will keep continue this line
if($name="alex"){$message="Welcome ". $name;}

Comment: `die()` will not clean the page, it just terminate the script and displays remaining output if there is any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read your script for top to bottom, including anything outside of `<?php ?>`. When using `die()` your script stops then and there.

```
<?php $a = "something"; ?>
<html>
  <p><?php echo $a?></p>
  <?php die(); ?>
  <p>Never here</p>
</html>
```

Would output

```
<html>
  <p>something</p>
```

In your case do

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];

    //Field check
    if(!$name || !$password) {
       $message="please enter name and password");

    //Check name and password    
    } elseif ($name=="alex" && $password=="alex1") {
       $message="Welcome ". $name;

    } else {
       $message="Username or password incorrect"
    }
?>
<html>
<p>SIGN UP</p>
    <form action="testing.php" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name" />
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password"/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign up"/>
    </form>
    <div><?php echo $message?></div>
</html>
```

Also note that I'm using '==' to compare, not '='.

Comment: +1 Very nice answer. You beat me to the "=" that's causing the problem (that you identified), but laying the logic out so clearly only helps!