# PHP die clean all page

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP die() clean all page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13736007/php-die-clean-all-page)

I check field 1st, if all correct, will pass to user check than email & password checking...

Therefor I use die to stop code keep going

however When I use die(), it kill all page, any way to keep all page but only echo out $error_message

It looks like jump into another page when I use die()

```
<?PHP

session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['firstname']) && isset($_SESSION['lastname'])){
    header('location:member.php');
}

$firstname="";  $lastname="";   $email="";  $re_email=""; $error_message="";

if(isset($_POST['signup'])){
    $firstname=strip_tags(ucfirst($_POST['firstname']));
    $lastname=strip_tags(ucfirst($_POST['lastname']));
    $email=strip_tags(strtolower($_POST['email']));
    $re_email=strip_tags(strtolower($_POST['re_email']));
    $password=strip_tags($_POST['password']);
    $re_password=strip_tags($_POST['re_password']);
    $date=date("Y-m-d");

    if($firstname && $lastname && $email && $re_email && $password && $re_password && $age && $gender && $employment){}
    else{die($error_message="Please fill in all fields");}

    //USERNAME CHECKING////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    $connect=mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    $database=mysql_select_db("phplogin", $connect);
    $namecheck=mysql_query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
    $count=mysql_num_rows($namecheck);
    if($count!=0)
    {die("Username already taken");}
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    if($email==$re_email && $password==$re_password){}
    else{die("email or password do not match");}

    //Checking valid email//
    $strpos=strpos($email, "@");
    if(!$strpos)
    {die("This is not valid email");}

    //Password length//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    if(strlen($password)<6)
    {die("Password is too short");}


    echo "Register user!";
    $password=md5($password);

    $SQL="INSERT INTO users (email, password, firstname, lastname, date) 
    VALUES ('$email','$password','$firstname', '$lastname', '$date')";
    $result=mysql_query($SQL);

    session_start();
    $_SESSION['firstname']=$db_firstname;
    $_SESSION['lastname']=$db_lastname;
    header("location:member.php");

    }
?>
```

Comment: Um, change your `die()`'s to `echo`'s?

Comment: You just asked a question that's pretty much the same. The answer is still the same: don't use `die()`.

Comment: I tried change die to echo, yet it didn't work
when user don't fill all the form, it didn't show message and jump to next line - username already taken

Answer (score 2):

I believe your problem is here:

```
die($error_message="Please fill in all fields");
```

That means "When I die, assign this value to this variable".

It should look like this:

```
if(!isset($firstname) || !isset($lastname) || !isset($email) || !isset($password) || !isset($re_password) || !isset($age) || !isset($gender) || !isset($employment)){
    die("Please fill in all fields");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`die()` is a language construct that is equivalent to `exit()`, they output a message and terminate the current script. So, anything after die will not be displayed.

I think you could put the messages into a variable such as `$errorMsgs` which type is array before you save user data. And then if the `$errorMsgs` is not empty, it means there may be some troubles. At that time you could pass those error messages to the next step.

The code looks like this:

```
$errosMsgs = array();
if(!$ok) {
  $errosMsgs[] = "Error message";
}
if(empty($errorMsgs)) {
    //Data saving and redirect into another page
} else {
    //display errors
}
```